# Grep value of a specific key from a String, concatenated of key : value pairs

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed

I have a string which is concatenation of "key":"value" pairs separated by "," like-

```
KEY1:VALUE1, KEY2:VALUE2, KEY3:VALUE3
```

From this string, I have to grep for a specific string -- let's say KEY2 -- so the output of our command should be VALUE2.

Comment: Can the values contain quotes commas or colons? Is it JSON?

Answer (score 9):

Using PCRE-enabled `grep` implementations:

```
grep -Po '(^|[ ,])KEY1:\K[^,]*'
```

or `egrep` and `cut`:

```
grep -Eo '(^|[ ,])KEY2:[^,]*' | cut -d: -f2-
```

For both methods, the Value is not allowed to contain comma.

---

If you had proper `json`, e.g.

```
{ "KEY1":"VALUE1", "KEY2":"VALUE2", "KEY3":"VALUE3" }
```

you could use `jq`:

```
$ jq .KEY2
"VALUE2"
$ jq -r .KEY2
VALUE2
```

Answer (score 0):

With regular `grep` assuming VALUE doesn't contain a colon:

```
grep -o 'KEY2:[^,]\+' | grep -o '[^:]\+$'
```

Comment: @RoVo: added caveat

Answer (score 0):

To grep only the value

```
printf '%s\n' "$myString" | grep -Po "(?<=KEY2:)[^,]*"
```

or

```
grep -Po "(?<=KEY2:)[^,]*" <<< "$myString"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use awk, read key:value pair as record, read key, value as 1st and 2nd field.

```
awk -v RS=' *, *' -v FS=' *: *' '$1=="KEY2"{print $2}'  <<<$str
```

- `-v RS=' *, *'` set record separator to `,` and it's surrounding space
- `-v FS=' *: *'` set field separator to `:` and it's surrounding space
- `'$1=="KEY2"{print $2}'` print value if key found. change "KEY2" to your desired key value.